# Make created csv file downloadable

Tags: php, csv

With php, in a backend section, i generate some csv files :

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row, ';', '"');
}
fclose($fp);
```

Then, in a frontend view, i create a link to those csvs. The problem is that when a click on a link pointing to a csv, the content of this file is displayed in my browser, instead of downloading it.
First, i tried the target attribute

```
target="_blank"
```

Nothing changed. 
Then i saw in the internet that i could fix this with the header function

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row, ';', '"');
}
fclose($fp);
```

But the only thing that changed, was that when i click the button that generates the csv files in the backend, the browser propose me everytime to download the csv file. But what i want is to download it in the frontend.

Any solution ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you do your `fopen()`, open a file called `php://output`

Comment: Still asking me to download a file the backend, because of the header function

Comment: Note that the content type for a csv file is `text/csv`, not `application/csv` - [RFC4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
```

On the page that renders the file.

Comment: I just tried it, and after loading the page, the browser ask me to download the file whitout even clicking on the link! That's not what i want!

Comment: Does every csv link point to a different script to generate a csv file? You just need to put this on the script that generates the csv so it gets sent out when the csv is generated.

Comment: + 1, This is correct. Have a click event listener for an AJAX request, that calls a php page that executes the above code along with the CSV contents that you have.